# FillableLoaders Not Working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Android  FillableLoaders to my app using libraray https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/AndroidFillableLoaders But   while designing xml layout getting error like

```
Rendering Problems java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.github.jorgecastillo.svg.SvgPathParser.parsePath(SvgPathParser.java:52)   at com.github.jorgecastillo.FillableLoader.buildPathData(FillableLoader.java:301)   
at    com.github.jorgecastillo.FillableLoader.onSizeChanged(FillableLoader.java:192)   at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:16748)   
at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:16710)   
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16626)  
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)   
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)   
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)   
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)   
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)   
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)   
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout_Original(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)   
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:-1)   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)  
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)  
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)  
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
```

**My layout xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <com.github.jorgecastillo.FillableLoader
      android:id="@+id/fillableLoader"
      android:layout_width="306dp"
      android:layout_height="102dp"
      app:fl_fillColor="#13579e"
      app:fl_strokeColor="#13579e"
      app:fl_originalWidth="3066"
      app:fl_originalHeight="1024"
      app:fl_strokeDrawingDuration="2000"
      app:fl_fillDuration="5000"
      app:fl_clippingTransform="rounded"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      />

</FrameLayout>
```

**I am using the following dependencies:**

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'    
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'    
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'    
    compile 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fillableloaders:1.02@aar'
}
```

Comment: It is really being hard to findout the issue. so please try attaching this dynamically using FillableLoaderBuilder to your parentView. And see if error shows still

Comment: bro let me know if the error shows again. And if it didn't too.

Comment: As I know don't use this in FrameLayout. Add this block of code in something another layout... OK I will describe it as answer...

Comment: ok generally try putting your code block in a new layout. Then I can be sure that Frame inside frame wont work..

Comment: Bro i changed my layout it still not working .. i will post my java code also here please wait

Comment: ok bro. I am leaving now for few hours. And I will edit my question as your comments and issues. Stay cool.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.

The root layout of the library you are using is already a `FrameLayout`. You should use a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` as root, unless you want to display only one child at any given time. Either add these block of codes

```
  <com.github.jorgecastillo.FillableLoader
  android:id="@+id/fillableLoader"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  app:fl_originalWidth="@integer/original_svg_width"
  app:fl_originalHeight="@integer/original_svg_height"
  app:fl_strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"
  app:fl_fillColor="@color/fill_color"
  app:fl_strokeWidth="@dimen/stroke_width"
  app:fl_strokeDrawingDuration="@integer/stroke_drawing_duration"
  app:fl_fillDuration="@integer/fill_duration"
  app:fl_clippingTransform="waves"
  />
```

inside another root layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or try adding this dynamically in your view

```
    FillableLoaderBuilder loaderBuilder = new FillableLoaderBuilder();
    fillableLoader = loaderBuilder
    .parentView((FrameLayout) rootView)
    .layoutParams(params)
    .svgPath(Paths.JOB_AND_TALENT)
    .originalDimensions(800, 800)
    .strokeWidth(strokeWidth)
    .strokeColor(Color.parseColor([Color]))
    .fillColor(Color.parseColor([Color]))
    .strokeDrawingDuration([Duration])
    .fillDuration([Duration])
    .clippingTransform(new PlainClippingTransform())
    .build();
```